# Screen height gets smaller when using UIInput and Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, ngui

I am trying to create an input field with NGUI and Unity for my android app. When the keyboard appears on screen the NGUI screen mashes together in the height? How can I avoid this?

When building to iOS it is not a problem so it seems to be Android related?

Hoping for help in this matter and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know Unity creates project for eclipse before compiling this project open  AndroidManifest.xml for Activity where you want to avoid this behaviour declare

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

May be somewhere in Android compile settings you could find this preferences.

Comment: I added this but didn't help :-/